# Conditionally wrapping content with a Razor Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using Razor I want to conditionally wrap some content in a `<span>` element based on a boolean  property of my model. My guess is that I will need to use [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx), but I'm finding it tricky to get them right.

My model goes something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool IsBar { get; set; }
}
```

and in my view I'd like to be able to use something similar to:

```
<a href="/baz">
    @Html.WrapWith(Model.IsBar, "span", @This content may be wrapped, or not)
</a>
```

where it would render:

```
<!-- Model.IsBar == True -->
<a href="/baz">
    <span>This content may be wrapped, or not</span>
</a>

<!-- Model.IsBar == False-->
<a href="/baz">
    This content may be wrapped, or not
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would always wrap content with span and let css handle all the presentational logic, if any

```
<a href="/baz">
    <span class="@(Model.IsBar ? "bar" : "")">This content may be wrapped, or not</span>
</a>
```

And apply css rules to `.bar`

```
span.bar
{
   //some style rules
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still ends up with the `<span>` rendered to the browser

Comment: @PhilPeace that is point of my answer. I would always render span to browser, and if I needed any extra presentational logic applied, I would control that by css

Answer (score 2):

you could do an If in your editor Template view with Razor

```
@if(Model.IsBar)
{
      <span>This content may be wrapped, or not</span>
}
else
{
       This content may be wrapped, or not
}
```

**UPDATE**

or you could do your custom helper

```
@helper Foo(bool bar)
{
     @if(bar)
     {
      <span>This content may be wrapped, or not</span>
     }
     else
     {
       This content may be wrapped, or not
     }

}
```

Comment: Yeah - this what I could fall back to, but if I were to use this all over my view it would add visual clutter so I'd like to be abel to do it in a Helper